# Chat firebase structure

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I am trying to creating a working chat app, but I got to a problem. I've structured my database like so:
[image]

Now when I am actually calling to a method to add a new message that's where the problems arise. Apparently sometimes it doesn't add anything, sometimes it adds a message correctly, and at other times it just goes into an endless loop of adding the last message. I've no clue what went wrong, I am out of options. Every help would be appreciated immensely.

When I press 'send' button:

```
@objc func handleSendTapped() {
    guard let userID = user?.uid else { return }
    let messageID    = UUID().uuidString
    let members      = [currentUserUID, userID]
    let ref          = Database.database().reference()

    let message = Message(
        to: userID,
        from: currentUserUID,
        content: messageTextField.text,
        timeStamp: Date().timeIntervalSince1970 as NSNumber)


    // Upload to Chats
    let chatsRef = ref.child("chats")
    chatsRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        var didAddChat = false

        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let dataSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot {
                if let chatsDict = dataSnapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
                    if let chatMembers = chatsDict["members"] as? [String] {


                        if chatMembers[0] == self.currentUserUID && chatMembers[1] == userID {
                            // add to existing chat
                            let chatID = dataSnapshot.key
                            didAddChat = self.addChat(to: chatID, with: messageID, and: members)
                            self.addChatToUserChats(withChatID: chatID)
                            self.addChatMessage(withMessage: message, andMessageID: messageID)
                        }


                        // New chat
                        if !didAddChat {
                            guard let chatID = chatsRef.childByAutoId().key else { return }
                            didAddChat = self.addChat(to: chatID, with: messageID, and: members)
                            self.addChatToUserChats(withChatID: chatID)
                            self.addChatMessage(withMessage: message, andMessageID: messageID)
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    // New chat when there's no chats at all
                    guard let chatID = chatsRef.childByAutoId().key else { return }
                    didAddChat = self.addChat(to: chatID, with: messageID, and: members)
                    self.addChatToUserChats(withChatID: chatID)
                    self.addChatMessage(withMessage: message, andMessageID: messageID)
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

These are the methods I call inside the handleSendTapped:

```
func addChat(to chatID: String, with messageID: String, and members: [String]) -> Bool {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let chatsRef = ref.child("chats")

    let values: [String : Any] = [
        "lastMessageID" : messageID,
        "members"       : members
    ]

    chatsRef.child(chatID).updateChildValues(values)
    print("added message to: \(chatsRef.child(chatID).description())")
    return true
}

func addChatToUserChats(withChatID chatID: String) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let userChatsRef = ref.child("userChats")
    userChatsRef.child(currentUserUID).child("\(chatID)").setValue("")
}

func addChatMessage(withMessage message: Message, andMessageID messageID: String) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let chatMessages = ref.child("chatMessages")
    let chatMessageRef = chatMessages.child(messageID)
    let values: [String : Any] = [
        "contents" : message.content!,
        "timeStamp": message.timeStamp!,
        "from"     : message.from!
    ]
    chatMessageRef.updateChildValues(values) // set
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the endless loop of new chat item because you're adding the new chat item inside the observer for adding new chat item. When the observer receives the new chat item added notification you're adding a new chat item which in-turn triggers another notification and this loops on. You need to add a new chat item outside the observer for that triggers when new chat item is added.